# @font-face Not Working in Chrome for Android

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, fonts, font-face

I'm using an `@font-face` declaration to call a font on a website and it displays in *IE, FF, Chrome, even Mobile Safari*. However, the font is not displaying in **Chrome 18.0.1025308** for **Android (4.1.2)**.

The syntax I'm using is [fontspring's](http://www.fontspring.com/) bulletproof syntax, and I'm having a real problem determining what is preventing the font from displaying properly.

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'jump_startregular';
    src: url('wp-content/uploads/fonts/jstart-webfont.eot');
    src: url('wp-content/uploads/fonts/jstart-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('wp-content/uploads/fonts/jstart-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('wp-content/uploads/fonts/jstart-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('wp-content/uploads/fonts/jstart-webfont.svg#jump_startregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Better use google web fonts ...

Comment: @Mr. Alien why are google web fonts supposed to be better?

Comment: They don't depend on @font-face

Comment: @Luca You've many font-face making engines out there which fail in some or the other browser where google web fonts are generally preferred as they are widely supported

Comment: @ChrisFrank Wrong, they are `@font-face`

Comment: Or you can use a stylesheet to import.

Comment: issue is that if you have a specific font to use (e.g. for brand awareness) you are forced to use that - Best practice would be getting the different formats from font squirrel, am I right?

Comment: @Mr. Alien Although google web fonts seem great, the problem I'm running into is that the font I'd like to use isn't in their library.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be related to your `font-family` declaration (I can't tell because you haven't posted that part). If, for example, you had this:

```
font-family: fghjkjh, 'jump_startregular', sans-serif;
```

...Chrome for Android would simply pretend that fghjkjh is installed (but really use the default Android font) and ignore everything else. (Not sure if this is a bug or a feature.)

In which case, the solution is to move 'jump_startregular' to the front - and possibly add a `local` source to the `@font-face` block instead, which probably causes problems with other older browsers.