# Mobile Firefox and Chrome not recognizing @font-face

Tags: html, css, mobile, fonts, font-face

I am using a particular font on my website. Firefox and Chrome recognize it on the PC (locally and server), but not on mobile (Firefox and Chrome). I am using @font-face in my CSS file.

I have the fonts uploaded on the server. I don't know what to try since it does work on the computer. Any help greatly appreciated.

Here is my HTML:

```
 <div class="welcome">WELCOME</div><div class="home">HOME</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'typographicaregular';
    src: url('../fonts/typographica.regular-webfont.woff') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/typographica.regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;}

.welcome {
    width: 47%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: 'typographicaregular', sans-serif;
    font-size: .7em;
    letter-spacing: 26px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #004391;
}
.home {
    width: 85%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -40px auto 0;
    font-family: 'typographicaregular', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #004391;
}
```

It should show the actual font on my Android phone and iPad, not a generic san-serif font.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054358/font-face-not-working-in-chrome-for-android

Comment: Tigerrrrr, my takeaway from that is to use Google fonts, but it doesn't have Typographica font like I need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@font-face Not Working in Chrome for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054358/font-face-not-working-in-chrome-for-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a duplicate from: [@font-face Not Working in Chrome for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054358/font-face-not-working-in-chrome-for-android)

The problem may be related to your `font-family` declaration (I can't tell because you haven't posted that part). If, for example, you had this:

```
font-family: fghjkjh, 'jump_startregular', sans-serif;
```

...Chrome for Android would simply pretend that fghjkjh is installed (but really use the default Android font) and ignore everything else. (Not sure if this is a bug or a feature.)

In which case, the solution is to move 'jump_startregular' to the front - and possibly add a `local` source to the `@font-face` block instead, which probably causes problems with other older browsers.

"Taken word for word from the link mention above"

If this doesn't work, I suggest you use google fonts instead.

Comment: No problem! (sorry for the late response)